# Rounding of read pointcloud when using matplotlib's tick_params

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, open3d

I have the following issue and do not have clue where to report this or if this is just an issue on my machine. Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

# X | line of code in question 
plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=1) 

# read pointcloud
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("../pointcloud_820_1880.pcd")
points = np.asarray(pcd.points)
print(points)
```

This outputs:

```
[[ 829. 1899.  101.]
 [ 835. 1899.  112.]
 [ 831. 1899.   92.]
 ...
 [ 821. 1899.   77.]
 [ 821. 1899.   77.]
 [ 821. 1899.   77.]]
```

If I comment out line X, where I call `plt.tick_params()`, I get the following output, which is what the file actually contains:

```
[[ 829.88127 1899.80715  101.29749]
 [ 835.85224 1899.55968  112.49222]
 [ 831.75095 1899.8053    92.93788]
 ...
 [ 821.95337 1899.16928   77.34216]
 [ 821.96948 1899.16988   77.6308 ]
 [ 821.97324 1899.17001   77.72527]]
```

How does this interfere with each other? Why, how, what?

EDIT: opened this issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24497

Comment: What happens if you first read the point cloud and later call the `plt.tick_params` method?  My expectation is, you load the real data, not the integer floor.  If my expectation is correct, somehow `plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=1)` changes some default that is reverberated in reading the points cloud, probably a setting in Numpy, but all this is speculation… (hence a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @gboffi Thanks for your answer! If I move `plt.tick_params()` anywhere after `o3d.read_point_cloud()` I do not get the rounding issue. That means I also don't get the rounding issue if I first read the pointcloud, then set the `tick_params` and then convert to a numpy array.  I guess the best place to open an issue is on the open3d github..

Comment: Imo the best place to open an issue is Matplotlib, because it's Matplotlib that triggers the problem… at any rate, now you can proceed with your work and that was the real issue, wasn't it?

Comment: @gboffi ok I guess I will open an issue on matplotlib. Yes, I can proceed now... I mean it wasn't at work blocker really. The goal of this post was to understand what causes this behaviour because it took me quite some time to find it and I want know whether other places of my code are also affected...